# How to quickly view huge PNG images in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, performance, png, image-viewer

I need to view and zoom into selected parts of PNG images around 10,000x10,000px, ~10MB.

When I open these images with Preview, it takes over a minute to load and then is very slow to show the image in the proper resolution when zooming in.

Is there some tool that can view PNGs much faster? Either a native OS X app or something that can run in X window that I can compile from source will do.

Comment: add a tag that you're talking about OS X. And IMO put it in the title too.

Comment: @barlop While you don't have [edit privileges](http://superuser.com/privileges/edit) yet, you can still suggest an edit that can be approved by higher-rep users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [Xee](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19978/xee) a try.

Comment: If only Xee had quickLook plugins... as it is this this has definitely solved my problem; I can only wonder why this has not been made the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Previewing only, I don't know in OSX, but in Windows thumbnails mode in folder does a pretty good job at that. Other solution is using Photoshop Automate batch feature, or using an open source tool like imagemagik to generate (you could even make an automated task to be done for example at iddle times, etc) thumbnails from all the folder, and so would have that other folder as a "fast previewer". But if need zooming non of these will do. You need to load the thing fully.(unless it is always same area to zoom in, then you can as well do a batch that what outputs is the zoomed in, and reduced version)