# How do I open a 60M png image on OSX

Tags: macos, memory, images

Alright, so I've been looking around on this site on how to open a big PNG image. The [question](https://superuser.com/questions/250266/how-to-quickly-view-huge-png-images-in-os-x) I found was about a 10M png. Xee apparently did the job.

So, I downloaded Xee for my 60M file, but it crashes. So does iPhoto, Pixelmator and previewer. In the Pixelmator and Xee case, I actually had to kill the computer, and restart it. It crashed so 'hard' I couldn't get it to respond again.

How do I open this file? (and zoom it)

Specs:

```
newly acquired macbook pro: 4gb memory, 2.3ghz i7
58M png image
approx: 15000x30000 pixels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid I don’t have a solution for you. I checked and could not find anything that is guaranteed to work because this scenarios is rare enough that it just doesn’t get mentioned enough in web pages to [register on search engines](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&q=osx%20view%20extremely%20high%20resolution%20image&oq=osx%20view%20extremely%20high%20resolution%20image&gs_l=serp.3...14994.16081.0.16271.10.10.0.0.0.4.143.701.3j4.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.zsaR39aFVn4).

What I can do is to explain your predicament.

The image may be 58MB *on disk*, but PNG is a compressed format, so to display it, the system has to decompress it in memory. A 15000x30000 image (which is *huge*) requires 429MB to display if it is black-and-white! If it is true-color (32-bit), then it will require **1.68GB** of RAM to store.

The aforementioned 10MB image may have been 10MB on disk, but only requires 381MB of RAM to decompress (10000×10000×4Bpp = 381MB). Yours is 4.5x larger.

While you have enough total RAM, you would need to find a program that is designed to use that much memory, and unfortunately most just aren’t capable of it due to various factors. For example, even if a program uses 32-bit or even 64-bit pointers, they may uses (image, file, etc.) libraries that use smaller ones, so at some point it ends up crashing.

Graphics-*editors* (like Photoshop) are most likely to be able to open the file because they usually use their own libraries and are deigned to support extremely large, memory-demanding graphics files.

Comment: sounds like he needs Gimp and 2gb of SwapSpace, I'm unsure of how setting those things up on a Mac would work. Either way it would operate very slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me, even though it didn't conclude to the answer. I added my own answer how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Synetech's answer, and help from a friend, I figured it out using Photoshop.

But, starting up photoshop and opening the image in it didn't work either. What I had to do was go into performance settings in photoshop, and increase the amount of memory to  be used. The standard 70% wasn't sufficient so I had to use more.

The approx 3.2GB worked fine, and I was able to actually zoom in to the image just fine.